# Excel VBA: Code hang caused by writing to cells individually (how to write as block when they are non-consecutive?)

Tags: vba, excel

I have an issue(using VBA with Excel 07) where my code is slowing down when running through a long loop.  I'm 95% sure this slowdown is caused because I'm writing to many different cells individually instead of as one block.

However, I'm not sure how to fix this as most of the cells I need to write to are non-contiguous and non-consecutive. Take the below for example:

```
    ActiveSheet.Range("b2").Value = Sheet6.Cells(regionMembers(i), 2)
    ActiveSheet.Range("j4").Value = Sheet6.Cells(regionMembers(i), 4)
    ActiveSheet.Range("e6").Value = Sheet6.Cells(regionMembers(i), 5)
    ActiveSheet.Range("d22").Value = Sheet6.Cells(regionMembers(i), 6)
    ActiveSheet.Range("d23").Value = Sheet6.Cells(regionMembers(i), 7)
```

This is a small section of the cells that need to be written to (the total is around 150 per loop and the loop is the extent of the array regionMembers(), where region members can hold up to 40-50 values).

Is there any way for me to write the values on sheet6 to a variant array and then paste it to the active sheet in one block?

I know for a range like "A1:A100", you can presumably set a range to ("A1", "A100"), then store all the values you want pasted in an array then do something like:

```
myRange.Value = myArray
```

But I cannot figure out how to do this when the range is non-consecutive.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you turned off calculations and display updates for this?

Comment: You (and Bathsheba) were both right... turning of calculations fixed the problem!  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be a problem per se, but you might need to optimise the process a little. I'd try switching calculation off during the macro (if the logic allows you to):

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
```

Then switch it back on again afterwards

```
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

You can't assign a non-contiguous range to a value: `myRange.Value = myArray` only works for a contiguous range. (The underlying variant, myArray, doesn't support non-contiguity).

Comment: Wow, I had ScreenUpdating & DisplayAlerts off, but Calculation left on xlCalculationAutomatic...., changing it to xlCalculationManual for the duration of the sub made a remarkable difference and fixes the issue.

Thanks!